# Flink listener is not getting called when using statementSet.execute

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm using flink 1.13, using statementSet.execute but added a listener in Flink  stream env,  onJobSubmitted is getting called when the job is submitted (no compile issues with plan) but to bug the pipeline, I have a string field in Kafka but int field in table DDL, so it is failing at task manager, but somehow onJobExecuted with throwable is not getting called, am I missing something?